# Sufficient Criteria for Minimum of differentiable Function

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a sufficient criteria which would tell me, if a point is the global minimum of a as often as you want differentiable real-function with arbitrary dimension.
*I am not looking for a criteria which works only in special cases, instead one which holds for all functions*.

Comment: A short answer is no, there is no universal criterion for global maxima or minima. Even for functions of a single real variable you must check if local extrema are global extrema. On the other hand, you can easily (at least in principle) distinguish a minimum point from a maximum point.

Comment: Is there no criteria yet found or is it not possible that one exists?

Comment: Well, a point $x_0$ is a global minimum of $f$ if $f(x_0) \leq f(x)$ for every $x$. Any condition ensuring this inequality is a sufficient criterion. In your question there is too much freedom about the generality you want: *all* functions is such a strong request! However you should keep in mind that mathematics is not the art of finding recipes: almost every interesting problem is solved by using any piece of information you have.

Comment: not all function, all differentiable functions as often as you like. I mean checking if the gradient is zero is a method of reducing the domain in an efficient way instead of testing all values which is not possible. now you have a smaller domain of suitable points but now you restart with testing. I wonder if theres way to decrease the domain again.

Comment: Smooth functions are so many! Smooth functions can have arbitrarily many critical points, but how can you isolate a *global* minimum if you *restrict* the domain? If you need a *global* minimum, then you *must* compare the value of the function at that point with *all* the other values attained in the whole domain. In different words: whenever you look at a small part of the domain, you lose any global insight.

Comment: only points which satisfy gradient(x) = 0 can be points which are my global minimum. So i reduced the search space of points which can be my global minimum. i only have to compare them to all other points in the set not to all points which i excluded because they did not fullfil the property gradient(x) = 0. My question is there a criteria to further reduce the search space? For example in one dimension you can use the second derivation to exclude all maximas. In more dimension the test of hessian matrix can be indecisive. is there a alternative test which works for all functions?

Comment: There is no theoretical difference between one dimension and higher dimension. Even in 1D the second derivative can vanish at a critical point! For functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or higher) it is almost impossible to deal with third or higher derivatives. And how do you handle functions whose derivatives of *any* order vanish at a minimum point?

Comment: yes it seems there's nothing you can do thank you